# Is it possible to get HTML tag autocompletion in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, erb

I just installed Netbeans 6.7 for Ruby and one of the things that bugs me is I have to type both the opening and closing HTML tags even though it seems to recognize that I have completed the opening tag.

Is it possible to configure it to automatically type the closing HTML tag for you, as some other IDEs do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall how to configure it as it's been a while since I've used NetBeans (switched to TextMate), but I do remember that I would get html autocompletion. Perhaps NetBeans is not recognizing the file as HTML and therefore the HTML functions aren't available. Make sure it's recognized the file as RHTML/ERB. If you're typing HTML inside an RB file, you might not have access to HTML functionality.

Comment: "If you're typing HTML inside an RB file, you might not have access to HTML functionality." -> Yes, maybe that's the reason. These are .html.erb files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, and this didn't exist at the time, but Netbeans 7.3 has great HTML support now, with auto complete and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ can do autocomplete for most of the languages. You can find the list of supported languages here

http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/auto-completion-HOWTO.php

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans for PHP (I got the standard NetBeans dstribution and added the plugins) and it completes them for me.